# How can I input a result % to change the initial value correctly?

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to reverse predict an initial required value from the predicted result % and cannot find the correct formula to do so (assuming the drop in value from input to result is identical).

Here is an example of the data:

```
A        B         C    D            E             F        G
Input    Result    %    New Input    New Result    New %    Required %
2000     700       35   1857.05      557.05        30       30

A = Raw data
B = Raw data
C = B / A
D = (A - B) * 1.4285 'This is the formula i need help with, i want this formula to calculate the required new input to receive result G but can only get result G currently by manually tweaking the number in D formula or causing a circular reference
E = D - (A - B)
F = E / D
G = User input
```

I would like the user to type in a required % in G and see the New Input change to the number required to result in that % in F.

Hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that number (using a bit of algebra) equivalent to 1/(1-G) ? 1/(1-0.3) = 1.4285.

Comment: Yes! That is the answer, Thanks! If you can submit it as an answer instead of a comment I can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a one-time thing? In that case, use [`Goal Seek`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-goal-seek-to-find-the-result-you-want-by-adjusting-an-input-value-320cb99e-f4a4-417f-b1c3-4f369d6e66c7)